# modifyiing master record of detail record in Master detail relationship in salesforce to salesforce connection

Tags: apex, trigger, master-detail, salesforce2salesforce

I've set up a connection between 2 sandboxes. **PL box** and **JIRA box**
there is a master detail relationship between product launch and JIRA (product launch is the master and JIRA is the detail)
Now **product launches can only be created in the PL box** and **JIRA in the JIRA box**.
the connection is set up such that product launches created in the PL box are published to the JIRA box. And JIRAs are created in the JIRA Box and are automatically published to Product launch Box and are automatically assigned the right record(Product Launch)
Now any updates to the JIRA record(like Name,Status) in the JIRA Box are automatically synced to the production box. However when i change the Product launch(master record the JIRA is pointing to) in the JIRA box, the changes aren't reflected in the product launch box. It is still under the same product launch, other custom fields will still change

Here's the code in trigger we use to programmatically send JIRAs

```
List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection> connectionRecords = new List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection>();
    PartnerNetworkConnection connection = [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection where ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted' and ConnectionName = 'Our company'];

    for(JIRA__c jira : trigger.new) {

        PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();
        newrecord.ConnectionId = connection.Id;
        newrecord.LocalRecordId = jira.Id; 
        newrecord.ParentRecordId = jira.Product_Launch__c;
        newrecord.SendEmails = false; 

        connectionRecords.add(newrecord);

    }
```

We have checked the connection log in both the boxes and there are no errors at all. Is there a possible workaround or solution for this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can please provide the details about how did you debug. As salesforce to salesforce the normal debugging won't work. So if you have not debug properly you won't be able to get the logs correctly.

Please follow the below steps for debugging SF 2 SF if you have not then provide the exact error or the log details for above.

To begin capturing Debug Logs for a Connection User open the following URL in your browser:

https://XXX.salesforce.com/p/setup/layout/AddApexDebugLogUser?retURL=%2Fsetup%2Fui%2FlistApexTraces.apexp&UserLookupInput_lkid=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
&UserLookupInput=Connection%20User

Replace XXX with your salesforce instance, UserLookupInput_lkid is the ID of the Connection User and UserLookupInput is the User name. You can find the user ID of the connection user, by inspecting the CreatedById for a record created by this user. (eg. via eclipse or Force.com explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the connection to the **PL box** instance on the **JIRA box** instance to publish the Product launch records? Have you selected to fields you are modifying on the Product launch records to be shared? On the **PL Box** have you subscribed to the Product launch records and mapped the fields being shared?

These are the first things I would check. Note that just because the Product launch records are published to the **JIRA box** doesn't automatically mean changes to Product launch records made on the **JIRA box** will be pushed back. The sharing back to the **PL box** has to be configured also.